# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'username' referenced before assignment (in a return part of a function)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

```
def login():
    userinfo = open("userinfo.txt","r")
    userinforec = userinfo.readline()
    username1 = input("What is your username?\n")
    while userinforec != "":
        field = userinforec.split(",")
        username = field[0]
        password = field[1]
        name = field[2]
        age = field[3]
        year = field[4]
        mathseasy = field[5]
        mathsmed = field[6]
        mathshard = field[7]
        hiseasy = field[8]
        hismed = field[9]
        hishard = field[10]
        if username != username1:
            print("Error, username not found")
            break
        else:
            password1 = str(input("What is your password?\n"))
            if password == password1:
                print("password accepted")
                writereport(username)
            else:
                print("Error, password not accepted")
                login()
            userinforec = userinfo.readline()
    userinfo.close()
    return username
```

Exactly as stated in the title, when I run this piece of code it says that in the final line (return username) is referenced before assignment.

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'username' referenced before assignment

I looked at other threads and it all occurred if the variable is outside of a function however here it is not. Do I still need to use `global` or is there another way to get around this?

Comment: if the `while userinforec != "":` loop is never entered, then `username` is never initiated. Set it to some default value outside of the `while` loop

Comment: If you mean setting the variable 'username' outside of the while loop, i already have @RNar

EDIT:
never mind, username1 is outside the loop

Comment: @SkidSolo, no, you don't. you initialize `userinfo`, `userinforec` and `username1`. The first line that `username` is initialized to any value is inside of the while loop (ie, `username = field[0]`)

Answer (score 0):

If your while loop is never entered, e.g. because `userinforec == ""` you are returning `username` before assigning it with any value.

Add `username = ""` before your while loop so that is has a value, if it is never assigned during the while loop.